# Legal Rights Question - Android Application Naming

Tags: android

Good Day,
I would like to know, can you use any name for an Android application, or is there a place to see if you can use your name for the application? I just want to make sure that the name is within Legal rights?

I have googled the app name that I want to use and did not find anything related to the name, I do not know of any other sources to have a look at.

Just want to know if I will be in Legal rights.

Thank You,
Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where you are and where you plan to sell your app.  The best place to search would be the Patent/Trademark agency in your country, or the country(s) you plan to distribute your app in.  However, most developers don't bother to do this.  Generally, when you start to create an app, you register your app name and identifier through your App Store (Google Play, Amazon, iTunes App Store) and if that app name is already in use, the store will reject the name.  That's the best indicator of whether the name is already used by someone else, since almost all apps are distributed through those three App Stores.  That said, it is possible that even after distributing your app, someone will complain that you are using their trademarked name.  If you verify this to be true, you just have to unpublish your app, rename it to something similar, and publish it with a new app id.  I've never had a problem after publishing 70-80 apps over the years.